# Update of single table using join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

I have a select using two tables via a join. I need to update first table using the second table field. Select as follows

```
select R.f1, Z.f2,R.f3 
FROM
(select * From Table1 where f2<>'xx' and f3='z') R inner join
(select * From Table2 where f3='xx')             Z 
 ON R.f1⁼Z.f1 and R.f4=Z.f4
```

How could I update correspond to same select of Table1 (SET R.f2=Z.f2)?

```
UPDATE 

(select * From Table1 where f2<>'xx' and f3='z') R inner join
(select * From Table2 where f3='xx')             Z 
 ON R.f1⁼Z.f1 and R.f4=Z.f4
 SET R.f2=Z.f2
```

When I tried, I get a response that

> target table R of the UPDATE is not updatable

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join in `update` statements using the following....

```
update t
   set t.Column = value
  from Table t
 inner join OtherTable ot on t.Id = ot.TID
 where somecondition = true.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should perform the update on `table1` and join it to the second subquery. The conditions on `table1` from the first subquery could be applied in the where clause:

```
UPDATE table1 r
JOIN   (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE f3 = 'xx') z  ON r.f1 ⁼ z.f1 AND r.f4 = z.f4
SET    r.f2 = z.f2
WHERE  r.f2 <> 'xx' AND r.f3 = 'z'
```